# Error 40 in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a website in Asp.net that I have installed on my server, and my website's database in SQL Server 2008 R2. My website has pages that contain ActiveX components. When I run my website on the server the ActiveX components are working correctly, but there is a problem when I run website from client.

The pages that do not contain ActiveX components work correctly and I can get and insert data from database. In the pages that contain ActiveX components it gives me SQL Server error number 40, that it could not open the connection.

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: check your connection string in your config file

Comment: I hope your activeX component is not making call directly to the SQL server ?

Comment: connection string is worked correctly because pages with out active x component can connect to database

Comment: steve : which prevent me to make activex component call directly to sql server ? remember in server the site work correctly and active x component work correctly .

Answer (score 0):

As Steve B implies in his comment the problem lies in the ActiveX component making a call to the database directly.  The connection string in your app specifies a connection made from the Web server to the Database server.  These connections work because your firewall settings allow for inbound connections to the Database server from that Web server.  When the connection is set in the ActiveX control to connect directly to the Database, you are getting connection failures because the firewall is blocking the inbound connections from the clients running the ActiveX component.  The fix is to redesign your application so the ActiveX component that lives on the client machine no longer makes calls directly against the database; make use of web services or something of that nature.  If the clients are all internal to the domain (aka this is a private app and will never be public facing), chances are the Firewall isn't properly configured to allow internal connections to the database server.